# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/pdf

Tags: jetty, pdfbox

This does work with Jetty 9

```java
@GET
@Path("pdf/file")
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response getFile() {
    String fileName = Environment.getFilePath() + testFile;
    File file = Environment.getFile(fileName);

    Response response = Response.ok((Object) file).build();
    return response;
}
```

this

```java
@GET
@Path("pdf/plain")
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response getPlainPDF() {
    String formName = Environment.getFilePath() + testFile;
    PDDocument pdfDoc = PDF.getPDFDocument(formName);
    PDStream ps = new PDStream(pdfDoc);
    try {
        OutputStream outputStream = ps.createOutputStream();
        Response response = Response.ok((Object) outputStream).build();
        return response;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error creating PDF response " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

fails with "MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/pdf". Would it be possible to programatically create a PDF with PDFBox and deliver it as PDF File without saving it first somewhere to disk ?

Comment: `@GET`, `@Path`, and `@Produces` are not part of Jetty.  Is this [tag:jersey] or [tag:jax-rs] related?  If so, you might want to include those tags in your question.

Comment: You can save to OutputStream: public void save(OutputStream output) - i that what you wanted?

Comment: @Joakim yes the Annotations are part of jax.ws.rs which I ussually use to generate  org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder methods...worked best for me so far to get valid Jetty answers for small prototype projects

Comment: @Tilman I would like to have the same PDF File answer as in the first result but without saving it as file if that is possible ?

Comment: @user3732793 that is the very thing I answered in my comment. For example you can save to a BufferedArrayOutputStream. Or to any OutputStream.

Comment: unfortunatetly my Java skills are not that good to just do it...if you don't mind a litte example for that ? or some nice introduction to outputstreams ?